# Webpack: Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm working with some UMD code output by TypeScript via `tsc`.  It's just a simple build right now as I get things figured out:

```
tsc; ./node_modules/.bin/webpack lib/WebApp/BootcampWebAppSuite.js public/lib/index.js
```

Unfortunately, when I go to load the resultant `.js` file in my browser (which seems to look alright at a glance?), I end up getting this exception:

[image]

Admittedly, this has been a bit difficult to google for as I have no way to search for `"."` (quote period quote).

Comment: Could you add some code that reproduces your problem? It's hard to tell just by the error messages you've posted.

Comment: Honestly, if it comes to being absolutely essential, I'm more than happy to.  But it's not a simple setup.  I could paste the output file somewhere?  I'd rather just get a few common gotchas for this problem to begin with if there are any.

Comment: As I said, it's hard to tell purely by the error messages you get; if you have a `require(".")` statement (or something similar) in your code, that's likely the source of the error. Webpack will typically continue to build when it can't find a module, but refuse to load in the browser, as it does in your case; I can't say anything more specific than that.

Comment: I did end up determining that if I tell typescript to build using commonjs as opposed to UMD, things work.  Not sure if that hurts me in the long run though.  I had some relative node-style `index` imports, although in an attempt to troubleshoot this, I removed all of them.  So I don't think it's that.  I'll see about getting code up shortly, again, nothing proprietary. :)

Comment: @Omega CommonJs also fixes this issue for me.  Only problem is I am getting this error with CommonJs: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4039